# How to loop Ruby hash and remember/access previous value?

Tags: ruby, loops, hashmap, haml

I have a hash that maps the number of orders by calendar week in the controller:

```
@orders_by_week = {
  "42" => 56,
  "43" => 64,
  "44" => 76
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how the relative growth in percentages week over week would be computed. I've gotten so far in my HAML view:

```
- @orders_by_week.each do |week, orders|
  = "#{week}: #{orders} (#{ (orders - prev_week_orders / prev_week_orders)*100 }%)"
```

but haven't figured out a way to get `prev_week_orders` elegantly.

How would this be done?

Comment: That is not valid Ruby code.

Comment: @sawa it's valid HAML.

Comment: @p11y The first one is not even HAML. Furthermore, the tag only mentions ruby.

Comment: @sawa I think you're being a bit fussy here. The hash is just example data, would you rather see a cryptic controller action without context? I think it's the right thing to do. The HAML is perfectly clear and converting it to Ruby, you'd have to add a `puts` or something to make it a reasonable example.

Comment: @p11y: If the OP asks someone to do his work for him without even getting paid (and let's face it, that's what SO *does*), it's just polite to take the few seconds to format his code properly so that it can be copied, pasted and tested without having to figure what data structure he is talking about or having to install additional libraries which aren't even relevant to the problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I get it and I largely agree, but in the above case the example is very short and simple – it's not even worth investing the energy discussing this ;-) Of course if someone pastes 50 lines of HAML, I refuse to format it for them as well.

Comment: Hi guys and thank you for your comments. I'll try to be more precise and elaborate in the future.

Comment: Even if you were using a valid Hash and anyone understood your real problem, complex code belongs in the model, not the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 hash = {'42' => 56, '43' => 64 , '44' => 76}
 all_keys = hash.keys

 hash.each_with_index do |(key,value),index|
   puts "#{key}: #{value} (#{ (value - hash[all_keys[index-1]] / hash[all_keys[index-1]])*100 }%)" unless index == 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
- @orders_by_week.to_a.unshift([0, 0]).each_cons |(prev_week, prev_week_orders), (week, orders)|
  = "#{week}: #{orders} (#{ (orders - prev_week_orders / prev_week_orders)*100 }%)"
```

The `to_a.unshift([0, 0])` is there to set the first value for `(prev_week, prev_orders)`; otherwise, it would start at the second week.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
orders_by_week = { "42"=>56,"43"=>64, "44"=>76 }

pct = []
enum = orders_by_week.values.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [56, 64, 76]:each>
loop do
  orders = enum.next.to_f  
  pct << (100*(enum.peek-orders)/orders).round(2)
end
pct
  #=> [14.29, 18.75]
```

[Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) raises a `StopIteration` exception with the enumerator is at the end.  [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking the loop.